# Java. Где располагается объект hash таблицы для HashMap?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь разобраться с устройством hash таблиц на примере взаимодействия с HashMap но никак не могу найти сам массив-таблицу. Где она находится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

395 строка в реализации от Oracle JDK:

```
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

Но для изучения хеш-таблиц я бы посоветовал более классические реализации без привязки к конкретному языку:

- [Хеш-таблица](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)